# Problem evaluating $\int x^2 \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} \, \mathrm d x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble with the Schaum *Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables* (1968, Murray R. Spiegel) item $14.246$:

$$\int x^2 \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} \, \mathrm d x = -\frac {x (\sqrt {a^2 - x^2})^3} 4 + \frac {a^2 x \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} } 8 + \frac {a^4} 8 \arcsin \frac x a + C$$

I attacked this by substituting $z = x^2$ which led me to:

$$\int x^2 \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} \, \mathrm d x = -\frac 1 2 \int \sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} \, \mathrm d z$$

There is a standard result here (14.122 in Schaum):

$$\int \sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} \, \mathrm d x = \frac {2 a p x + b p + a q} {4 a p} \sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} - \frac {(b p - a q)^2} {8 a p} \int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} }$$

Setting $a \gets 1$, $b \gets 0$, $p \gets -1$, $q \gets a^2$, $x \gets z$ leads us to:

$$\frac 1 2 \int \sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} \, \mathrm d z= \frac {2 z - a^2} 8 \sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} + \frac {a^4} {16} \int \frac {\mathrm d z} {\sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} }$$

Then I went to *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*  (1964: Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun) to use item $3.3.27$:

$$\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} } = \dfrac {-1} {\sqrt {-a p} } \arcsin \left( {\dfrac {2 a p x + b p + a q} {a q - b p} }\right) + C$$

which is appropriate where $a > 0$ and $p < 0$, as they are here: $a = 1$, $p = -1$.

using the same substitutions as above, this gives us:

$$\frac {2 z - a^2} 8 \sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} + \frac {a^4} {16} \int \frac {\mathrm d z} {\sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} } = \frac {2 z - a^2} 8 \sqrt {z (a^2 - z)} + \frac {a^4} {16} \left( {-\arcsin \frac {2 z - a^2} 4}\right) + C$$

and substituting back for $z$:

$$= \frac {2 x^2 - a^2} 8 \sqrt {x^2 (a^2 - x^2)} + \frac {a^4} {16} \left( {-\arcsin \frac {2 x^2 - a^2} 4}\right) + C$$

All well and good with the left hand term, this easily equates to $-\dfrac {x (\sqrt {a^2 - x^2})^3} 4 + \dfrac {a^2 x \sqrt {a^2 - x^2} } 8$

But I'm stumped as to how to get to $\dfrac {a^4} 8 \arcsin \dfrac x a$ with that last term.

Any pointers? Many thanks.

**EDIT**: While it is true that [Find a primitive of $x^2\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575933/find-a-primitive-of-x2-sqrta2-x2) answers the solution of this integral, I am specifically interested in the solution which uses the given substitution and standard integrals.

Comment: do you mean just proving that the integral gives arcsin? it is an established integral identity otherwise

Comment: "It is an established integral identity" -- well yes I know it is, I got it out of the given book. The exercise here is **proving** this identity.