# Incorrect cancellation of fraction with correct answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If you cancel (incorrectly) the 6 in $\frac{26}{65}$, you get the (correct) equation $\frac{26}{65} = \frac{2}{5}$. What other fraction exhibits this property?

I tried considering only the simple case where the fraction is of the form $\frac{10a+n}{10n+b}$ (as in the example), then attempting to solve $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{10a+n}{10n+b}$ to get $n(10a-b) = 9ab$. I was thinking of using divisibility tricks, but am not getting anywhere.

The case of the forms $\frac{10n+a}{10n+b}$ and $\frac{10a+n}{10b+n}$ are easy; you just get $a = b$. I haven't attempted higher than two digits or non-rationals. It would be interesting to see a complicated formula not necessarily involving a ratio of integers which works out to a correct answer with incorrect cancellation.

Comment: What would a "non-rational" example look like?

Comment: @Travis I guess something like $ \sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}, (f \cdot g)' = f' \cdot g' $ and so on

Comment: The classic I always thought was 16/64 = 1/4.

Comment: Similar to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49657/bad-fraction-reduction-that-actually-works

Comment: @PaoloFranchi Square both sides of the radical equation and simplifying gives $2 \sqrt{a b} = 0$, so there are only solutions have one of $a, b$ zero.

Comment: @PaoloFranchi Also, the ansatz $f(x) = e^{ax}, g(x) = e^{bx}$ leads to a one-parameter family of solutions to $(fg)' = f' g'$ given by the solutions to $a + b = a b$.

Comment: @Travis I was just giving examples of "wrong operations" that could be solved as equations, since this would answer the final question of the OP. (Unfortunately,) $ \sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} $ happens to have only trivial solutions

Comment: 98/49=2. Cancel the 9's.....

Comment: The _Journal of Irreproducible Results_, Vol. 35, No. 1 published a tongue-in-cheek article about this by Ben Ruekberg back in 1993 or so titled “Simplified Mathematics” that you can find at http://www.textfiles.com/humor/COMPUTER/maths.txt which included many examples of this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite of few fractions that exhibit this property. They are also referred to as "lucky fractions".

Here is a paper on this topic that you might find useful: [Lucky fractions](http://www.rowan.edu/colleges/csm/departments/math/facultystaff/osler/87%20Lucky%20Fractions.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

We'll solve $$\frac{10 a + n}{10 n + b} = \frac{a}{b},$$ or equivalently $n (10 a - b) = 9 a b$; to interpret the l.h.s. as a ratio of $2$-digit numbers, we restrict to solutions for which $1 \leq a, b, n \leq 9$.

Reducing modulo $9$ reduces $n(10 a - b) = 9 ab$ to $$n (a - b) \equiv 0 \pmod 9.$$ In particular $n$ and $(a - b)$ must have two factors of $3$ between them. This gives three cases:

**CASE 1** $(3^2) \mid n$ : This forces $n = 9$, and canceling gives $10 a - b = ab$. Rearranging gives $(a + 1)(10 - b) = 10$, so since $1 \leq a, b \leq 10$ we must have either $a + 1 = 10$, or one of $a + 1$ and $10 - b$ is $2$ and the other is $5$. These cases respectively give $$\frac{99}{99}, \quad \frac{19}{95}, \quad \frac{49}{98}.$$

**CASE 2** $3 \mid n$ and $3 \mid (a - b)$: We may as well assume $9 \nmid n$, as this is the content of case $1$, so, $n = 3$ or $n = 6$. If $n = 3$, simplifying gives $$10 a - b = 3 a b ,$$ and rearranging gives $(3 a + 1)(10 - 3 b) = 10$, which forces $a = b = 3$, giving $$\frac{33}{33} .$$ If $n = 6$, simplifying and rearranging gives $(3 a + 2)(20 - 3 b) = 40$. The factors of $40$ of the form $3 a + 2$ for $1 \leq a \leq 9$ are $5, 8, 20$, and these lead to $a = 1, b = 4$ and $a = 2, b = 5$, $a = 6, b = 6$, which respectively give
$$\frac{16}{64}, \quad \frac{26}{65}, \quad \frac{66}{66}.$$

**CASE 3** $9 \mid a - b$: Since $1 \leq a, b \leq 9$, we have $a = b$, and so $n (10 a - b) = 9 a b$ simplifies to $n = a$, giving the trivial cases
$$\frac{11}{11}, \ldots, \frac{99}{99} .$$

In summary, the nontrivial solutions are
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\frac{16}{64}, \qquad \frac{19}{95}, \qquad \frac{26}{65}, \qquad \frac{49}{98}}}. $$

Of course, we can also look for "false cancellations" of the form $$\frac{10 n + a}{10 b + n} = \frac{a}{b} ,$$ but this is exactly the equation formed by taking the reciprocals of both sides of the above equation and interchanging the roles of $a, b$, so this equation leads precisely to the four reciprocals, $\frac{64}{16}$, etc., of the above solutions.

(There are other two-digit "false cancellation" fractions, corresponding to other equations, but there are all trivial in some sense; they have the forms $\frac{d0}{e0}$ and $\frac{dd}{ee}$ for digits $d, e$.)

Answer (score 0):

One other springs to mind: $\frac{16}{64}$.

Comment: Actually it is an answer to the question "What other fraction exhibits this property?" in the first paragraph.  To be sure it's not the only other such fraction.

Answer (score 0):

The lucky fractions $ \frac{16}{64}, \frac{19}{95}, \frac{26}{65}, \frac{49}{98} $ and their inverses are the solutions to the first question.

About your final (vague) suggestion, I have tried some "wrong operations" concerning fractions, roots and powers, and it seems that the nicest results can be obtained as solutions of

$$ \frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d}. $$

For instance, we have $ \frac{2-8}{k+2k} = \frac{2}{k} + \frac{-8}{2k}$, which works for $k \neq 0$.

Reference: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28a%2Bb%29%2F%28c%2Bd%29%3Da%2Fc+%2B+b%2Fd+over+the+integers