# Sum : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Prove that : $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$

---

I think this is known (see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/06/ShowAll.html)), I appreciate any hint or link for the solution (or the full solution).

Comment: For searching purposes: this is essentially the Dirichlet beta function evaluated at $3$.

Comment: Evaluate it’s integral $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^3}=\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can evaluate this sum using the residue theorem.  First, note that it may be extended out to $-\infty$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^3} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^3}$$

From the residue theorem:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^3} = -\text{Res}_{z=-1/2} \frac{\pi \csc{\pi z}}{(2 z+1)^3} = -\frac{1}{8}\text{Res}_{z=-1/2} \frac{\pi \csc{\pi z}}{( z+1/2)^3} $$

This residue involves taking the second derivative of the csc term.  Note that, for a generic function $f(z)$ having a triple pole at $z=z_0$:

$$\text{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{2!} \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}[(z-z_0)^3 f(z)]$$

so that

$$\text{Res}_{z=-1/2} \frac{\pi \csc{\pi z}}{( z+1/2)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{2!} \left[ \csc{\pi z} \cot^2{\pi z} + \csc^3{\pi z}\right ]_{z=-1/2} = -\frac{\pi^3}{2}$$

Putting this all together, we get the stated result:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Comment: I think you assumed that : $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{C_r} \frac{\pi \csc \pi z}{(2z+1)^3} =0$, I'm I right ?

Comment: @aziiri: Yes, depending on what you mean by $C_r$.  I just didn't feel the need to clutter up the derivation with such standard details.

Comment: @aziiri: the important thing to note here is that the sum may be evaluated like this because it could be extended to $-\infty$.  Not all such sums can (i.e. $\zeta(3)$), which is why some folks get confused when they see a result like this.

Comment: Let $P(k)$ and $Q(k)$ be polynomials. Then the integral will always go to zero if $\sum (-1)^{k} \frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Someone recently asked about $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{2m+1}}$. It too can be evaluated using contour integration. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762813/sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n12m1-frac-1m-e-2m-pi2m14/762858#762858

Answer (score 14):

Here is another way using Fourier analysis:
Let
\begin{equation*}
  f(t)=\begin{cases}
    t-t^2 & 0<t<1 \\
    -f(-t) & -1 < t < 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
be a function with period 2. Then we can express $f$ in a Fourer series:
\begin{equation*}
  f(t)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos n\pi t+b_n \sin n\pi t
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
  &a_n=\frac{1}{1}\int_{0}^{2}f(t)\cos n\pi t \, dt \\
  &b_n=\frac{1}{1}\int_{0}^{2}f(t)\sin n\pi t\, dt
\end{align*}
But $f$ is odd, so $a_n=0$.
It follows that
\begin{align*}
  b_n&= \int_{0}^{2}f(t)\sin n\pi t\, dt=\{ f(t)\sin n\pi t \text{ even}\}=2\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\sin n\pi t\, dt = \\
  &= 2\int_{0}^{1}(t-t^2)\sin n\pi t\, dt=\frac{4-4(-1)^n}{n^3 \pi^3}
\end{align*}
Plugging in $t=\frac{1}{2}$, we get
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{4}=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi^3n^3}\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}
\end{equation*}
But $1-(-1)^n=0$ only if $n$ is even, so
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{1}{16}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3\pi^3}\iff \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{equation*}

Comment: But how are you going to fix the economy using Fourier Analysis?!

Comment: That's classified.

Answer (score 13):

I'll show you a related series and then pick a special case. We'll start with $$\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{e^{ki\theta}}{k}=-\operatorname{Log}\left(1-e^{i\theta}\right)\tag{1}$$ and we'll take the imaginary part of both sides to get $$\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k}=\tan^{-1}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\tag{2}$$
where the second equality is true when we restrict $0\lt\theta\lt 2\pi.$ Then $$\int_{0}^{\beta}\!\!\int_{0}^{\alpha}\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\alpha=\int_{0}^{\beta}\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{1-\cos\left(k\alpha\right)}{k^2}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha=\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{k\beta-\sin\left(k \beta\right)}{k^3}\\=\int_{0}^{\beta}\!\!\int_{0}^{\alpha}\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\alpha= \frac14\left(\pi \beta^2-\beta^3/3\right)=\frac{\beta^2\left(3\pi-\beta\right)}{12}\tag{3}$$ This way, we see that $$\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{\sin\left(k \beta\right)}{k^3}=\frac{\beta^3-3\pi\beta^2+2\pi^2\beta}{12}$$ Now, just pick $\beta=\pi/2$ and $$\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)^3}=-\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{\left(2k-1\right)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

---

To fix some issues in convergence, I'll take my first equation and introduce a new variable $0\lt t\lt1$: 
$$\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{t^ke^{ki\theta}}{k}=-\operatorname{Log}\left(1-te^{i\theta}\right)\tag{1}$$ and then take the imaginary parts and let $t\rightarrow 1$:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\left[\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac{t^k\sin\left(k\theta\right)}{k}\right]=\lim_{t\rightarrow 1}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t\sin\left(\theta\right)}{t\cos\left(\theta\right)-1}\right)\right]=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}$$ and we proceed normally from here.

Comment: In your first displayed equation: (1) The convergence of the series needs to be established (it's not absolutely convergent, so the convergence isn't obvious). (2) Which branch of the complex logarithm are you choosing? (3) The summation index $k$ shouldn't appear in the exponent on the RHS.

Comment: Great answer (+1)

Comment: @JohnBentin I tried to improve my post, I'd like a feedback.

Comment: Yes, that's better! (+1)

Answer (score 9):

Consider the triple integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}dzdydx.$$

The region of integration tells us that $0<xyz<1$. Rewrite the integrand as a geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(xyz)^{2n}.$$

Replace the integrand with this geometric series and carry out the integration:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(xyz)^{2n}dzdydx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3},$$

which is the desired sum.  Now we proceed to find the value of :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2y^2z^2}dzdydx.$$

Make Eugenio Calabi's change of variables: $$x=\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(v)},y=\frac{\sin(v)}{\cos(w)},z=\frac{\sin(w)}{\cos(u)}$$

Compute the Jacobian Determinant and see:

$$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}=1+x^2y^2z^2,$$

which cancels with the integrand.  The region of integration becomes the open polytope described by inequalities:

$$0<u+v<\frac{\pi}{2},0<v+w<\frac{\pi}{2},0<u+w<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ where $$0<u,v,w<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

So computing the volume of the polytope will complete this proof. To compute the volume, we will need to decompose this figure into two tetrahedra. The volume of a tetrahedron has a very nice determinant formula. In particular,

Given vertices $v_1,...,v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the volume of the tetrahedron spanned by the vertices is $$\left |\frac{1}{6}\det \begin{bmatrix}v_2-v_1 \\ v_3-v_1\\ v_4-v_1\\ \end{bmatrix} \right|.$$

Consider the tetrahedron formed by vertices $(0,0,0),\frac{\pi}{2}e_i, 1\leq i \leq 3$ where $e_i$ is the ith standard basis vector. Use the determinant formula to see the volume of this tetrahedron is $\frac{\pi^3}{48}.$

Consider the tetrahedron formed by $\frac{\pi}{2}e_i, (\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}),1\leq i\leq 3$. Use the determinant formula to see that this volume is $\frac{\pi^3}{96}$

Add these volumes up to get $\frac{\pi^3}{32}$, which is the value of the original integral in question. Thus:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Comment: Thanks. I have been interested in these kinds of connections with sums and polytopes. I actually wrote a paper (not published) on the higher dimensional version of this polytope and how it evaluates a more general harmonic sum (you can easily get back $\zeta(2k)$ values as a bonus). Let me know if you are interested in seeing it.

Comment: That would be neat. I love infinite series. One of the first things that ever really amazed me.

Comment: @VivekKaushik how can i get that paper ? have you already published it ?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.ams.org/journals/qam/2018-76-03/S0033-569X-2018-01499-3/ or look at the arXiv preprint

Comment: [Michael Penn](https://www.michael-penn.net/) has made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1i5LUxglsE) where he uses this solution.

Answer (score 6):

The Polylogarithm function is defined as
$$\text{Li}_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^k}{k^s}$$
Now $$\text{Li}_3(i) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^k}{k^s}\,\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\,\text{Li}_3(-i) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^ki^k}{k^s}$$
Hence,
$$\text{Li}_3(i) - \text{Li}_3(-i) = 2i \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}\right) \,\,\,\, (\heartsuit)$$
[Now the PolyLogarithmic function satisfies a very nice identity
$$\text{Li}_n(e^{2 \pi ix}) + (-1)^n \text{Li}_n(e^{-2 \pi ix}) = - \dfrac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}B_n(x)$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)
Taking $n=3$ and $x=\dfrac14$, gives us
$$\text{Li}_3(i) - \text{Li}_n(-i) = - \dfrac{(2\pi i)^3}{3!}B_3(1/4) = i \dfrac{8 \pi^3}{6} \dfrac3{64} =i \dfrac{\pi^3}{16} \,\,\,\, (\diamondsuit)$$
Comparing $(\heartsuit)$ and $(\diamondsuit)$ gives us
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}\right) = \dfrac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the series into two yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2}}{(2 n+1)^{3}} &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 n+1)^{3}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 n+3)^{3}} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4 n+1)^{3}}+\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(-4 n-3)^{3}} \\
&=\frac{1}{64}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}}+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{64} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the theorem $$\pi \cot (\pi z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+z} ,$$
where $z \not\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t $z$ twice yields
$$
2 \pi^{3}\left(\cot ^{2} (\pi z)+1\right) \cot (\pi z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(n+z)^{3}}
$$
Putting $z=\frac{1}{4}$ yields

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2}}{(2 n+1)^{3}} = \frac{1}{64} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left[2 \pi^{3}\left(\cot ^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+1\right) \cot \frac{\pi}{4}\right]=\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}}$$

Answer (score 1):

For each non-negative integer $n$ define respectively
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x) := \frac{x^{n} \log^{2} x}{1 + x^{2}} \text{ for } x > 0,\quad J_{n} := \textstyle\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x)\,dx\\
g_{n}(x) := x^{n} \log^{2} x \text{ for } x> 0, \quad K_{n} = \textstyle\int_{0}^{1} g_{n}(x)\,dx.
\end{align*}
[Interpret $\int_{0}^{1}$ as $\lim \int_{r}^{1}$ as $r \to 0.$]  Note (and check) the following.

1. $\quad$ By repeated integration by parts there exists $K_{n} = 2/(n+1)^{3}$ for any non-negative integer $n.$       [Quote $x\log^{k} x \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$ for $k=1,2.$]  Thus $K_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$
2. $\quad$ For any non-negative integer $n,\ 0 \leq f_{n}(x) \leq g_{n}(x)$ for each $x > 0$ so that, by comparison, there exists $J_{n}$ with  $0 \leq J_{n} \leq K_{n}.$  Thus $J_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$
3. $\quad$  By substituting $1/x$ for $x,\ J_{0} = \int_{1}^{\infty} f_{0}$ so that there exists  $I := \textstyle\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{0} = \left[\int_{0}^{1} + \int_{1}^{\infty}\right] f_{0} = 2J_{0}.$
   [Interpret $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ here as $\lim \int_{r}^{R}$ as $R \to \infty$ and $r \to 0.$]

For any non-negative integer $k$ and $x > 0,$ in turn
\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{1+ x^{2}} = {\textstyle\sum\limits_{0}^{k}} (-1)^{n}x^{2n} + (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^{2k+2}}{1+x^{2}},\\
f_{0}(x) = \textstyle\sum\limits_{0}^{k} (-1)^{n}g_{2n}(x) + (-1)^{k+1}f_{2k+2}(x),\\
J_{0} = {\textstyle\sum\limits_{0}^{k}} (-1)^{n}K_{2n} + (-1)^{k+1}J_{2k+2} = 2\sum_{0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{3}} + (-1)^{k+1}J_{2k+2}.
\end{gather*}
Since $J_{2k + 2} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty,$ there exists $\ \ S:= \displaystyle\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{3}} = \frac{J_{0}}{2} = \frac{I}{4}.$

- What has been shown is that both the infinite integral $I$ and the infinite sum $S$ exist (which latter is already evident on other grounds) but more importantly $I = 4S.$ By a rather standard contour integration of an auxiliary function round a semi-circular contour indented at $0$ (as sketched out below) it can be shown that there exists $I = \pi^{3}/8;$ by the bye with proof of existence direct and independent of the reasoning above.  Thus $S = \pi^{3}/32.$

***Proof that there exists $I = \pi^{3}/8$*** $\quad$Let $ \varphi(z):= \displaystyle\frac{\log^{2}_{\pi/2} z}{1 + z^{2}}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}_{\pi/2}$$^{\dagger}$ with $z \neq i.$

Let  $\gamma_{Rr}$ with $R > 1 > r > 0$ be the anti-clockwise orientated, indented, `semi-circular' contour $L_{+} + \Psi_{R}+ L_{-} + \psi_{r}$ where respectively $\Psi_{R},\psi_{r}$ are the semi-circular contours with centres $0$ radii $R,r$ in the upper half-plane from $R$ to $-R$ and from $-r$ to $r$ and $L_{\pm}$ are the line segment contours on the real axis from $r$ to $R$ and from $-R$ to $-r.$

Now $\gamma_{Rr}$ lies in the cut plane $\mathbb{C}_{\pi/2}$  and encloses the simple pole $i$ of $\varphi$ with residue
$$\text{res}\,(\varphi,i) = \left.\frac{\log^{2}_{\pi/2} z}{i+z}\right|_{i} = \frac{\pi^{2}i}{8}.$$
By the Residue Theorem $\int_{\gamma_{Rr}} \varphi = 2\pi i(\pi^{2}i/8) = -\pi^{3}/4$ so that
\begin{align*}
-&\pi^{3}/4- \left[\textstyle\int_{\Psi_{R}} + \int_{\psi_{r}}\right] \varphi
 = \left[\textstyle\int_{L_{+}} + \int_{L_{-}}\right] \varphi = \cdots\\
&= \int_{r}^{R} \frac{\log^{2} x}{1+x^{2}}\,dx + \int_{r}^{R} \frac{(\log\,x+i\pi)^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\,dx\\
&= \left[2 \int_{r}^{R}\frac{\log^{2} x}{1+x^{2}}\,dx - \pi^{2}\int_{r}^{R}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,dx\right] + i\,[\,\overbrace{\cdots}^\text{real}\,]\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align*}
since for $r \leq x \leq R,$ on $L_{+},\ z = x$ and $\log_{\pi/2} z = \log x$ while on $L_{-},\ z = -x$ and $\log_{\pi/2} z = \log\,x + i\pi.$

The reader should check by the usual estimates that $\mathcal{I}_{Rr} = \left[\textstyle\int_{\Psi_{R}} + \int_{\psi_{r}}\right] \varphi \to 0$ as $R \to +\infty$ and $r \to 0.$

Hence by equating real parts at ($\ast$) and rearranging
\begin{align*}
\int_{r}^{R}\frac{\log^{2} x}{1+x^{2}}\,dx &=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{\pi^{3}}{4} + \pi^{2}\int_{r}^{R}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,dx\right]- \frac{1}{2} \text{re } \mathcal{I}_{Rr}\\
&\to -\frac{\pi^{3}}{8} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{2} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\,dx}_{=\,\pi/2} - \frac{0}{2}= \frac{\pi^{3}}{8}
\end{align*}
as $R \to +\infty$ and $r \to 0.$  Hence there exists $I = \pi^{3}/8.\quad\square$

$^\dagger\quad$ Note $\mathbb{C}_{\pi/2}$ (the plane cut along the `non-positive' imaginary axis) instead of $\mathbb{C}_{0}$ (the plane cut along the non-positive real axis) and $\log_{\pi/2}$ (the logarithmic branch on $\mathbb{C}_{\pi/2}$) rather than $\log$ (the more usual logarithmic branch on $\mathbb{C}_{0}$) so as to avoid the singularities of $\log$ along the negative real axis; both in order to validate use  of the Residue Theorem to follow.