# How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln(\tan x))^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate this integral ? 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln(\tan x))^2dx$$
I changed it to
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The integral is $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}=2J$$Where, $$J=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{x^2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2e^{-x}}{e^{-2x}+1}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k e^{-2kx}dx\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-(2k+1)x}dx\quad(\mbox{Can be justified by Fubini's theorem})\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}\Gamma(3)$$
The answer provided by RonGordon to this series can be found in the link provided by him. This shows that the integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi^3}{8}$.

Comment: WolframAlpha spat out an answer of $\frac{\pi^3}{8}$. It would be nice if we could equate your series to that value. My gut tells it's already been demonstrated somewhere on this site.

Comment: I'm trying to find its value.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n13/359687#359687

Comment: Thanks @RonGordon for the link to the series.

Answer (score 2):

Note

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln^2\tan x\ dx & \overset{t=\tan x}= \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}dt
=\frac{d^2}{da^2} \left( \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{a-1}}{1+t^2}dt\right)\bigg|_{a=1}\\
&= \frac{d^2}{da^2} \left( \frac\pi2\csc\frac{\pi a}2\right)\bigg|_{a=1}=\frac{\pi^3}{8}
\end{align}
where the general result $\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{a-1}}{1+t^2}dt= \frac\pi2\csc\frac{\pi a}2$ is used.