# evaluation of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

While evaluating some integrals I came across this one that got me stuck:
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$$
The result is from wolframalpha since I wasn't able to compute it.

Firstly I thought of series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, but it's wrong since we are not integrating in $(0,1)$ but in $(0,+\infty)$ so the series doesn't converge.

Then I tried with the substitution $x=\tan(t)$, and this way the integral reduces to

$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln^2(\tan(t)) dt$$

but got stuck again. Can anybody provide a solution?

Comment: If you're familiar with complex analysis, you can consider the integral of $\dfrac{\log^{\color{red}3}(z)}{z^2+1}$ along a keyhole contour. (The $3$ is not a typo). See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942594/170231) using real methods.

Comment: I suppose partial fractions with your original integral, $x^2$+1=(x+i)(x-i) should work

Comment: Huge ammount of duplicates for this question (one example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996765/alternating-sum-of-reciprocals-of-odd-squares?noredirect=1))... BillDubuque in approach.

Comment: contour integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Feynman’s trick to evaluate. Let
\begin{eqnarray}
I(s)&=&\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x^2}dx.
\end{eqnarray}
By Mellin's transform table from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html), you have
$$ I(s)=\frac{\pi}{2\sin(\frac12\pi s)}. $$
It is easy to get
$$ I''(1)=\frac{\pi^3}{8}. $$

Comment: Thank you, I forgot Feynman's technique.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** To exploit the series expansion, make a substitution over part of the integration interval.

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\tfrac1x}= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac1x\right)}{1+\frac1{x^2}}\,\frac{dx}{x^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx\\
\implies I = 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
I=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\left.I(a)\right|_{a=0}
$$
where $I( a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} d x$ is transformed to a beta function via $x=\tan \theta$. $$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \tan ^a \theta d \theta= \int_0^{\infty} \sin ^a\theta \cos ^{-a} \theta d \theta= \frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1-a}{2}, \frac{1-a}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2} \sec \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)
$$
Then $$
I=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\left[ \frac{\pi}{2} \sec \left(\frac{\pi a}{2}\right)\right] _{a=0}=\frac{\pi^3}{8} 
$$