# Is there a closed form for $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x) \sin^{-1}(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\ ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, polylogarithm

Is there a closed form this integral:

> $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x) \sin^{-1}(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\ ?$$

I came across this integral while I was working on [$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937912/closed-form-of-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x-right-sqrt1-x2).

Here is what I did:

**First** I tried subbing $x=\sin(\theta)$ which yields

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\theta\csc(\theta)\ln(\sin(\theta))d\theta$$
and I do not think using Fourier series for $\ln(\sin(\theta)$ is useful here.

**Second** I tried [the identity](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Potenzen_des_Arkussinus)

$$\frac{\sin^{-1}(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
\frac{(2z)^{2k-1}}{k{2k\choose k}},\quad |z|<1$$

From which, it follows

$$I=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
\frac{(2)^{2k-1}}{k{2k\choose k}}\int_0^1 x^{2k-2}\ln(x)dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty 
\frac{(2)^{2k-1}}{k(2k-1)^2{2k\choose k}}$$

and I do not know if I made it more complicated or easier here. any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{2 u}{1+u^2}$ to find
\begin{align}
-I &= \int \limits_0^1 \frac{-\ln(x) \arcsin(x)}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d} x = 2 \int \limits_0^1 \ln \left(\frac{1+u^2}{2u}\right) \frac{\arctan(u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= 2 \left[- \ln(2) \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\arctan(u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u + \int \limits_0^1 \frac{- \ln(u) \arctan(u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u + \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+u^2) \arctan(u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u \right] \\
&\equiv 2 \left[- \ln(2) \mathrm{G}  + \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3} + J\right] ,
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{G}$ is Catalan's constant. The series is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n13) and equals $\frac{\pi^3}{32}$. The remaining integral can be found by writing
\begin{align}
J &= \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+u^2) \arctan(u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u = \operatorname{Im} \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1 + \mathrm{i} u)}{u} \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \left[\ln(-\mathrm{i})\ln^2(1+\mathrm{i}) + 2 \mathrm{i} \int \limits_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1 - (1 + \mathrm{i}u))}{1+\mathrm{i}u} \ln(1+\mathrm{i}u) \, \mathrm{d} u \right] \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \left[\ln(-\mathrm{i})\ln^2(1+\mathrm{i}) + 2 \operatorname{Li}_2(1+\mathrm{i}) \ln(1+\mathrm{i})  - 2 \mathrm{i} \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1+\mathrm{i}u)}{1+\mathrm{i} u} \, \mathrm{d} u\right] \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \left[\ln(-\mathrm{i})\ln^2(1+\mathrm{i}) + 2 \operatorname{Li}_2(1+\mathrm{i}) \ln(1+\mathrm{i})  - 2 \operatorname{Li}_3(1+\mathrm{i}) + 2 \operatorname{Li}_3(1)\right] \\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{16} + \frac{\pi}{8} \ln^2(2) + \ln(2) \mathrm{G} - 2 \operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3(1+\mathrm{i}) \, ,
\end{align}
where we have used $ \operatorname{Li}_2(1+\mathrm{i}) = \frac{\pi^2}{16} + \mathrm{i} \left(\mathrm{G} + \frac{\pi}{4} \ln(2)\right)$.

Combining these results we obtain
$$ -I = \frac{3 \pi^3}{16} + \frac{\pi}{4} \ln^2(2) - 4 \operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3(1+\mathrm{i}) \, . $$

Comment: very nice solution (+1). thank you. I am familiar with such subbing but i missed it. by the way, the integral you did can be found using the nice identity $\ln(1+x^2)\tan^{-1}(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{2n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed a really nice power series! I haven't computed nearly as many series with harmonic numbers as you though, so it's easier for me to stick to integration here.

Comment: you did it nicely after all.