# How is it possible that $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I read from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8822/87646) that:

$$\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

How is this possible ?

$$\infty!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times\ldots$$

But
\begin{align}
1&=1\\
1\times2&=2\\
1\times2\times3&=6\\
&~\vdots\\
1\times2\times3\times\ldots\times50&=3.0414093201713376\times10^{64}
\end{align}

This is obviously increasing, so how does factorial of $\infty$ become $\sqrt{2\pi}$ ?

Comment: maybe the ! sign meant something else in that context?

Comment: Here: http://drorbn.net/MathBlog/2008-11/one/Gillet@FI-_What_is_infinity_factorial_(and_why_might_we_care)Q.pdf

Comment: Did you really have to work out all the factorials upto $50!$ numerically to know it was increasing?

Comment: Its a 'regularized product'. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html

Comment: @fretty No, I just wanted to *show* that it was increasing.

Comment: @Kartik you actually failed to show that (in the mathematical sense of 'show').

Comment: Agreed with @DanielRust, you just gave the first $50$ factorials you didn't **prove** that it's increasing

Comment: @DanielRust That is **not** in the *mathematical sense*.

Comment: Who cares about common sense?

Comment: @Kartik Common sense told me all the horses in the world is of the same color ... dude you need to prove things mathematically

Comment: @DannyCheuk I couldn't prove it so I asked this question.

Comment: To prove it's straightly increasing, yes; to prove that $\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$, sorry ... idk

Comment: @Kartik: My point was that it is obvious that it is increasing...to get from one factorial to the next you multiply by a number bigger than $1$. There was no need for you to work anything out numerically...

Comment: A host of wibbling pedants in this particular section of comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is taken from 
$$ 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot \ldots \cdot n= n!$$
This is the exponential of
$$ \ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)+ \ldots + \ln(n) = \ln(n!) $$
Now if you write formally the derivative of the Dirichlet-series for zeta then you have
$$ \zeta'(s) = {\ln(1) \over 1^s}+{\ln(1/2) \over 2^s}  +{\ln(1/3) \over 3^s} + \ldots $$
This is for some *s* convergent and from there can be analytically continued to $s=0$ as well from where the the formal expression reduces to
$$ \zeta'(0) = -(\ln(1) +\ln(2) +\ln(3)  + \ldots )$$
which is then formally identical to $ - \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n!)$ .

Now the slope of zeta at zero can numerically be approximated and gives a concrete number $\zeta'(0) \approx -0.91893...$. It can also analytically be determined to equal $\ln(1/\sqrt{2\pi})$ .

Finally, since the formal notations coincide (except of the sign) one goes to write the exponential of this value to become the "regularized" value of the infinite factorial.

Comment: How is determined that $\zeta'(0)=\ln(1/\sqrt{2\pi})$?

Comment: @veronika - I myself have it only numerically; one can use Pari/GP and introduce epsilon. I don't know how Pari/GP does it internally. And I have the remark, that it is analytically derivable, from any of the sources which I've read on these matters - but always assumed it is handled like a "well known standard knowledge", so didn't do deeper research for a source, sorry. Perhaps in the "Handbook of mathematical functions" (Abramowitz/Stegun, is online, google "HoMF")

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I've find the book https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/toc.htm I'll revise it