# Under what conditions, or how can be done that, one says that something divergent can have a value?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

Excuse my question, I just don't get it.

In this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506832/693774), is mentioned:

> Now if you write formally the derivative of the Dirichlet-series for zeta then you have
> $$ \zeta'(s) = {\ln(1) \over 1^s}+{\ln(1/2) \over 2^s}  +{\ln(1/3) \over 3^s} + \ldots $$
> This is for some *s* convergent and from there can be analytically continued to $s=0$ as well from where the the formal expression reduces to
> $$ \zeta'(0) = -(\ln(1) +\ln(2) +\ln(3)  + \ldots )$$
> which is then formally identical to $ - \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n!)$ .

That is, one ultimately gets $ - \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n!)$

In that same proof, mentions that $\zeta'(0)=-\ln\sqrt{2\pi}$

Ultimately, one would get to "$\infty!=\sqrt{2\pi}$"

Why the two values "$\infty$" and $\sqrt{2\pi}$ were assigned to be equal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your confusion is justified since an assignment is not the value of the sum, it is just the value of some analytic continuation for which the corresponding sum diverges. This is used as an "assignment" , but has nothing to do with the sum which of course has no value. The same is the case with the often misused "equation" $$1+2+3+4+\cdots=-1/12$$ Seems that above we have some similar variant to this.

Answer (score 5):

Two concepts need to be understood:

- analytic continuation
- formality

In mathematics when something is done "formally" that means it is not to be taken literally and no claim of logical rigor is made.

Thus $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s $ is true if $s>1$ when convergence of series is defined the way you saw it defined in secondary school. But this function can be **analytically continued** so that there is a holomorphic function $\zeta$  defined everywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at some isolated points, and one point in that domain is $-1,$ and $\zeta(-1) = -1/12,$ so then one **formally** writes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^{-1} = 1+2+3+\cdots = 1/12.$ But that doesn't mean that series converges to $1/12$ in the usual sense, nor necessarily even in any of the someone less usual senses.

Comment: I'm surprised by this explanation of the term "formal". I thought it meant that we're working with formal sums, i.e. syntactic objects for which the question of convergence is irrelevant but which still have well-defined operations that allow us to manipulate them in a rigorous way and prove "equations" where the $=$ refers to some equivalence relation.

Comment: @Karl : Formal power series (and maybe other formal sums) are things to which the word "formal" applies, but the word is broader than that. "Formal" means something fits into a _form_.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.