# How to easily prove Euler's theorem, $OI^2=R(R-2r)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If $R$ is the circumradius and $r$ is the inradius of some triangle $ABC$, with its circumcenter being $O$ and incenter being $I$, then how to prove: 
$$OI^2=R(R-2r)$$
I have seen many mentions of this theorem, and Euler's inequality is a corollary. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry) 
has a proof, but its quite tough to follow and long, so does anyone have a nicer proof? :)

Comment: There are different proofs in https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~njb65/Euler.pdf

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä That is awesome :)

Comment: And BTW, the formula is $OI^2=R(R-2r)$ so remember that square term.

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä Can you add that as an answer, I would like to accept it? :)

Comment: there is one in here,[which is originally from maa](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939827/euler-triangle-inequality-proof-without-words)

Comment: This is a famous result due to Leonhard Euler. It is a matter of taste which proof is the nicest one. You can use for example trigonometry, inversion, or Poncelet's porism. See http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~njb65/Euler.pdf for details.

Comment: In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/171641), I derive this relation.