# How to prove $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^k}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I've found this wonderful identity [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8814/funny-identities).

On the first spot it seems for me true, but I don't have any idea, how could it be proven. In simpler form: "how the hell...?" :-)