# Polynomial products

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, products

This problem  $$ \large \displaystyle\prod \limits^{14}_{k=1}\cos \left( \frac{k \pi }{15} \right) =\ ?  $$ I solved it in this way $$ x = \displaystyle \prod \limits^{14}_{k=1}\cos \left( \frac{k\pi }{15} \right) 
y \\
= \displaystyle\prod \limits^{14}_{k=1}\sin\left( \frac{k\pi }{15} \right) 
x. y\\
 =\displaystyle\prod \limits^{14}_{k=1}\sin\left( \frac{k\pi }{15} \right) \cos \left( \frac{k\pi }{15} \right) 
x. y \\
= \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{14} \frac{1}{2} \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}{15} \right) \\
= \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{14}\sin \left( \frac{2\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{4\pi }{15} \right) \cdots \sin \left( \frac{14\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{16\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{18\pi }{15} \right) \cdots \sin \left( \frac{28\pi }{15} \right) 
 \\
\text {Now} :\sin \left( \frac{16\pi }{15} \right) = \left( -1\right) \sin \left( \frac{\pi }{15} \right) \& \sin \left( \frac{18\pi }{15} \right) \\
= \left( -1\right) \sin \left( \frac{3\pi }{15} \right)\& \cdots \&\sin \left( \frac{28\pi }{15} \right)\\
 = \left( -1\right) \sin \left( \frac{13\pi }{15} \right) 
 x. y \\
= \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{14}\left( -1\right) ^{7} \bigg[ \sin \left( \frac{2\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{4\pi }{15} \right) \cdots \sin \left( \frac{14\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{\pi }{15} \right) \sin \left( \frac{3\pi }{15} \right) \cdots \sin \left( \frac{13\pi }{15} \right) \bigg] 
x. y\\
 =\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{14}\left( -1\right) ^{7}. y 
\text{ so} : x =-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^{14}  $$ the question is how I can solve it by Chebyshev Polynomials???  .  any help will appreciate

Comment: This was answered here : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/173274

Comment: ... and here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/how-to-prove-those-curious-identities/