# Evaluation of $\prod^{n}_{r=1}\sin \left(\frac{(2r-1)\pi}{2n}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

> Find value of $$\prod^{n}_{r=1}\sin \left(\frac{\left(2r-1\right)\pi}{2n}\right)$$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$P = \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{3\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{5\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)$$

Now we can write $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ Similarly $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{(2n-3)\pi}{2n}\right)=\sin \left(\frac{3\pi}{2n}\right)$

So we get $$P = \left[\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{3\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{5\pi}{2n}\right)\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \sin\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{2n}\right)\right]^2$$

Now How can i Solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: Same principle as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/evaluating-the-product-prod-limits-k-1n-cos-left-frack-pin-right) resp. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/how-to-prove-those-curious-identities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod^{n}_{r=1}\sin\frac{(2r-1)\pi}{2n}=\dfrac{\prod_{u=1}^{2n-1}\sin\dfrac{u\pi}{2n}}{\prod_{v=1}^{n-1}\sin\dfrac{2v\pi}{2n}} =\dfrac{\prod_{u=1}^{2n-1}\sin\dfrac{u\pi}{2n}}{\prod_{v=1}^{n-1}\sin\dfrac{v\pi}n}=\dfrac{F(2n)}{F(n)}$$

where $F(m)=\prod_{v=1}^{m-1}\sin\dfrac{v\pi}m$

Now from [How to prove those "curious identities"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/how-to-prove-those-curious-identities),

$$F(m)=\dfrac m{2^{m-1}}$$

Comment: In the division of product wouldn't there be some dividing by zero business going on

Comment: @DDD4C4U,  $$0<\dfrac{v\pi}n<\pi$$