# How do you find this product?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to find the exact value of the product $$P=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{1007} \sin {\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2015}\right)}$$

Comment: Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231/how-to-prove-those-curious-identities?rq=1

Comment: These days, you can find most products on Amazon... ;-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Stuck on a test because you can't find the product? Well, with [Amazon's (brand new) Yesterday Shipping™](http://gizmodo.com/5926922/what-if-amazon-did-yesterday-shipping), you'll already have the product! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By symmetry, your product is just:
$$ P = \sqrt{\prod_{n=1}^{2014}\sin\frac{n \pi}{2015}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2^{2014}}\prod_{n=1}^{2014}\left(\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i n}{2015}\right)-1\right)},$$
where the innermost product is the product of the roots of the polynomial:
$$ \frac{(x+1)^{2015}-1}{x}.$$
Hence, by Vieta's theorem:
$$ P = \sqrt{\frac{2015}{2^{2014}}} = \frac{\sqrt{2015}}{2^{1007}}.$$

Comment: Or more roughly put, $P \approx 0$.

Answer (score 5):

For all positive integers $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the following [finite product identity holds](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/24/01/):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi\,k}{n}\right)}=2^{\frac{1-n}{2}}\,\sqrt{n}~.$$

Since you have the good fortune that the pair of integers $1007$ and $2015$ satisfy the necessary arithmetic relationship, $\lfloor\frac{2015-1}{2}\rfloor=1007$, the above product identity applies.

Comment: Any idea about how to prove this identity?

Comment: @user157130 Good old fashioned induction is one option.

Comment: @user157130 Also, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1