# $2^{199}\sin(π/199)\cdots\sin(198π/199)$ Sine Product Series

Tags: trigonometry

What will be the value of $2^{199}\sin(\pi/199)\cdots\sin(198\pi/199)$ ?
I could have found in case the functions were cosine but what should i do in case of sine?

Comment: Try this method http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199431/product-of-repeated-cosec/1199444#1199444