# Evaluating limit $\lim_{k\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^k\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}$

Tags: limits

I stumbled across the following question which asked to evaluate...

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^k\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}$$
I at first tried writing few terms
$$\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac {x}{4}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac {x}{8}\right)}...$$
I used the Half-angle formula to write$$\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2}\right)}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}$$
Therefore,
$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}}{2}}...$$ 
As there are infinitely many two's in the denominator, the denominator goes to $\infty$ which means $$\lim_{k\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^k\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}=0$$

So..My question is ...Am I correct?... If not, Could you please give me some hint to how should I proceed ?

Comment: The numerator goes to infinity too, because $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^r}\right)$ tends to $1$. In particular, if $x=0$, the limit is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: Try looking here for some inspiration from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right)

Comment: have you tried to write $\prod=e^{\log \prod}=e^{\sum \log}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use$$
\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}=\frac12 \cdot \frac{\sin{\left(\frac {x}{2^{r-1}}\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}}
$$ giving, by a *telescoping product*,
$$
\prod_{r=1}^k\cos{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}=\frac1{2^k}\cdot\prod_{r=1}^k\frac{\sin{\left(\frac {x}{2^{r-1}}\right)}}{\sin{\left(\frac {x}{2^r}\right)}}=\frac1{2^k}\cdot\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin{\frac {x}{2^k}}}=\frac{\large\frac{\sin x}x}{\large\frac{\sin{\frac {x}{2^k}}}{\frac {x}{2^k}}}
$$ then let $k \to \infty$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 5):

Check by induction that 
$$ \sin(x) = 2^m\sin(2^{-m}x)\prod_{j=1}^m \cos(2^{-j} x)$$
since 
$$ \sin(x)=2^{}\sin(2^{-1}x)\cos(2^{-1}x)=2^{2}\cos(2^{-1}x)\cos(2^{-2}x)\sin(2^{-2}x)=.......$$
Then, 
$$\lim_{m\to \infty } \prod_{j=1}^m \cos(2^{-j} x) = \lim_{m\to -\infty } \frac{2^{-m}x}{\sin(2^{-m}x)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Comment: That is not the question: your $2^j$ should be $2^{-j}$.

Comment: Where I don't get your point. Can you be more precise?

Comment: How strange! You edited your answer to fix the problem that I pointed out. Now you are asking me where the problem is.

Comment: sorry I did not know that!!