# Find: $ \lim_{n \to \infty}S_n= \log \cos\left( \frac x 2\right)+\log\cos\left(\frac x 4\right) + \cdots + \log\cos\left( \frac x {2^n}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation

Find:
$$ \lim _{n→∞}S_n= \log\cos\bigg( \frac x 2\bigg)+\log\cos\bigg(\frac x 4\bigg) +\dots+ \log\cos\bigg( \frac x {2^n}\bigg)$$

Writing as :

$$S_n=\log\Bigl(\cos\frac x 2\cdot\cos\frac x 4\dotsm\cos\frac x {2^n}\Bigr)$$

makes it more complicated. There must be an easier way.

Comment: You should use the fact that $\sin(2x)=2\cos(x)\sin(x)$ and use telescoping.

Answer (score 2):

Writing as a product actually helps a lot because
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$(The partial product is $
\prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) = \frac{\sin(x)\csc(x/2^n)}{2^n}
$.) Can you finish it from here?

Comment: thank tou, could you show the reason of 1st line?

Comment: A great explanation is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2143980