# Product of squared sines: $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left[ \sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2 n}\right) +\sin^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2 n}\right)\right]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, products

I have a double product

$$a(n)=2^{2 (n-1)^2} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \prod_{j=1}^{n-1}
\left[
  \sin^2 \left(\frac{k\pi}{2 n}\right) +\sin^2 \left(\frac{j\pi}{2 n}\right)
\right]$$

which always gives integers. I would like to have a closed form for this or something more intuitive without sines/complex numbers.

I have tried methods from [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right) but I can't seem to evaluate this expression.

Every new insight is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks a lot like domino tiling formula, so perhaps backtracking to a eigenvalue problem would help.

Comment: I don't get integers: e.g.  $a(3) = 3675/2$.

Comment: @Phicar I will look into that. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right. I accidentally wrote it to n instead of to n-1, $a(3)=192$. I changed that now. Thank you for the fast reaction.

Comment: Appears to be http://oeis.org/A007341 .  The OEIS entry does not give any closed form in the Formula section, but it does give two alternatives.