# If $x=2\pi/2009$, then evaluate $\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x \cdots \cos 1004x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been recently trying to solve a continued product of cosines:

> If $x=2\pi/2009$, then evaluate
>   $$\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x \cdots \cos 1004x$$

I have found formula for this which says product of this series is $\pm(1/2^n)$.

I'm recently in 11th, so please try to give this proof according to my knowledge

Comment: This post lack a lot of context. First, have a look at mathjax, to improve your equations.  Then add your thoughts on the problem.  It'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right