# Prove $\prod_{r=1}^{(n-1)/2} 2\cos \frac{\pi r}{n}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, induction, products

I would like to know how to prove that
$$\prod_{r=1}^{(n-1)/2} 2\cos\frac{\pi r}{n}=1~~~~~\text{where $n$ is odd}$$
I have tried induction and using trigonometric identities to attempt to transform the product into something more helpful, but nothing has worked.

It may be more helpful to think of the product as
$$\prod_{r=1}^{n} 2\cos\frac{\pi r}{2n+1}=1$$

Many thansk for your help.

Comment: Try $\sin(2x)/\sin(x)=2\cos(x).$

Comment: @Somos thanks for the tip!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product of cosines: $ \prod_{r=1}^{7} \cos \left(\frac{r\pi}{15}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Somos's tip is useful. In the second parameterization, write the product as$$\frac{\prod_{r=1}^n\sin\frac{2\pi r}{2n+1}}{\prod_{r=1}^n\sin\frac{\pi r}{2n+1}},$$then note the numerator's sines have the same values as the denominator's, but in another order. In particular, replacing $2r$ with $2n+1-2r$ when $2r\ge n+1$ produces a permutation of $\{1,\,\cdots,\,n\}$. For example, if $n=2$ the numerator is$$\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\sin\frac{4\pi}{5}=\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\sin\frac{\pi}{5}.$$

Comment: Wow, that was simple, thank you!

Comment: Would you mind justifying why replacing $2r$ with $2n+1-2r$ when $2r\ge n+1$ produces a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent You keep the evens from $2$ to $n$ inclusive, then convert the evens from $n+1$ to $2n$ inclusive into the odds from $1$ to $n$ inclusive.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAngles.htm)

$$\cos(2n+1)x=2^{2n}\cos^{2n+1}x+\cdots+(-1)^n\cos x$$

If $\cos(2n+1)x=-1=\cos\pi\implies(2n+1)x=(2r+1)\pi$

$\implies x=\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}; 0\le r\le2n$

So, the roots of $$2^{2n}c^{2n+1}+\cdots+(-1)^nc+1=0$$ are $\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}; 0\le r\le2n$

Using [Vieta's Formulas](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Vieta%27s_Formulas)
$$\prod_{r=0}^{2n}\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=-\dfrac1{2^{2n}}$$

Exclude $r=n$

$$\prod_{r=0,\ne n}^{2n}\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2^{2n}}$$

Now if $r_1+r_2=2n+1,\cos\dfrac{(2r_1+1)\pi}{2n+1}=\cos\dfrac{(2r_2+1)\pi}{2n+1}$

$$\implies\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2^{2n}}$$

Now $\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}>\dfrac\pi2\iff4r+2>2n+1\iff r>\dfrac{2n-1}4$

So, if $m=n-1-\left\lceil \dfrac{2n-1}4\right\rceil$

$$\implies(-1)^m\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2^n}$$

If $2r+1>\dfrac{2n+1}2,   0>\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=-\cos\dfrac{2(n-r)\pi}{2n+1}$

$$\implies\prod_{m=1}^n\cos\dfrac{m\pi}{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2^n}$$

Comment: Thanjs. Why is $0\le r\le2n$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent, As $m$ degree equation has $m$ roots

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how you've used $m=n-1-\left\lceil \dfrac{2n-1}4\right\rceil$ in the implication immediately afterwards. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Also, if $r=0$ then isn't it false that $$\frac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}>\frac{\pi}{2}$$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent, For the last query, where do you find its contradiction ?

Comment: 3 lines (that have text) up from the bottom of your answer.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent,  For these $m,$ we take $$-\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}=\cos\left(\pi-\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}{2n+1}\right)=?$$ Observe that these values $2(n-r)$  actually fill the even values of $m$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117906/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-a-level-student).