# What is the value of $\sin 1 ^\circ \sin3^\circ\sin5^\circ \sin 7^\circ \sin 9^\circ \cdots \sin 179^\circ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> What is the value of
>   $\sin 1 ^\circ \sin3^\circ\sin5^\circ \sin 7^\circ \sin 9^\circ \cdots \sin 179^\circ $ ?

The question is indeed intriguing. We could start by condensing it using $\sin \theta = \sin (180-\theta)$, This reduces the problem as the products till $89^\circ$.  But that doesn't help proceed.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You probably mean $180°$ ?

Comment: Are those degree signs or exponents?

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/college.math.j.47.5.322.pdf

Comment: @AndrewLi Their degrees. Henry just edited them for me!

Comment: $90^\circ$ can be written with `90^\circ`

Comment: @NickGuerrero I checked out your link. I don't see how's that gonna help.

Comment: @SmarthBansal Well, it lays out how to figure out the sin of any degree. You can do that for all you terms and manually calculate it. Most brute force way to do it

Comment: try using the imaginary versions of sin. If I remember correctly, there is a nice one for the evens when you do that.

Comment: I mean, just trying the above expression in mathematica doesn't seem to work. Maybe using the ideas in the paper will simplify to something

Comment: @RobbieVanDerzee Something just tells me that that'll work!

Comment: The answer seems to be $2^{-89}$. See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E89+(%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E89+sin(deg(2k%2B1))+)).

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884271/evaluate-prod-i-189-sin-i/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1

Comment: $\sin\theta=\sin(90°-\theta)$ is wrong !!!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh I see what you meant. Corrected it in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in a comment by Hans Lundmark in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1), we have
$$
\sin nx=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin\left( x + \frac{k\pi}{n} \right)
$$
The product we want is
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{89} \sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{180} \right)
=
\prod_{k=0}^{90-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{180} + \frac{k\pi}{90} \right)
=
\frac{\sin\left(90\frac{\pi}{180}\right)}{2^{90-1}}
=
\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2^{89}}
=
\frac{1}{2^{89}}
$$

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I would say using that first equation does give me the goosebumps. I'm not used to using that equation. :P

Comment: @SmarthBansal, we all learn something every day. I learned that equation today researching your question. That's the fun of MSE.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[image]

The product of the chords in this figure is

$(2\cos \frac {2\pi}{5})(2\cos \frac {\pi}{5})(2\cos 0)(2 \cos -\frac {\pi}{5})(2\cos -\frac {2\pi}{5}) = 2^5\prod_\limits {n=-2}^2 \cos \frac {n\pi}{5}$

If we map this figure to the complex plane the product of those lengths = $|(1+e^{\frac {\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {3\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {5\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}})|$

Note: $(z+e^{\frac {\pi i}{5}})(z+e^{\frac {3\pi i}{5}})(z+e^{\frac {5\pi i}{5}})(z+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}})(z+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}}) = z^5 + 1$

Evaluated at $z= 1$

$2^5\prod_\limits {n=-2}^2 \cos \frac {n\pi}{5} = 2\\
\prod_\limits {n=-2}^2 \cos \frac {n\pi}{5} = 2^{-4}$

And this generalizes:

$\prod_\limits {n=1}^k \cos \frac {(2n-1)\pi}{2k} = 2^{-(k-1)}$

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer! I don't understand how you map those up in the complex plane? (I mean how do you know for instance that the second chord is $1+ e^{3\pi i /5}$?)  (Sry new to this type)

Comment: The "roots of unity."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity  It falls out of DeMoivre's theorem.  if $z = \rho (\cos \theta + i\sin \theta) =\rho e^{i\theta}$ then $z^n = \rho^n (\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta) =\rho^n e^{i n\theta}$ working backwards if $z^n = -1$ we can back into the possible values of $\theta$

Comment: why are there two $1+ e^{7\pi i /5}$? in $|(1+e^{\frac {\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {3\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {5\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}})(1+e^{\frac {7\pi i}{5}})|$?

Answer (score 6):

Let us use $\sin(1^\circ) = \sin(179^\circ) = \cos(89^\circ)$, etc., to rewrite the product as
$$\prod_{i=1}^{45} \cos^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{180} (2i - 1) \right).$$

Now, $\pm \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{180} (2i-1) \right)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 45$ are roots of the polynomial $P_{180}(x) + 1$, where $P_n$ is the Chebyshev polynomial such that $P_n(\cos \theta) = \cos (n\theta)$.  In fact, since $-1$ is the minimum possible value of $P_n(x)$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$, they are all double roots; and this accounts for all 180 roots of the polynomial.  On the other hand, $P_{180}(x)$ has the form $2^{179} x^{180} + \cdots + 1$, so $P_{180}(x) + 1$ has the form $2^{179} x^{180} + \cdots + 2$.  Therefore, the square of the product above is equal to the product of roots of this polynomial, which is $\frac{2}{2^{179}} = 2^{-178}$; and the original desired product is $2^{-89}$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answering. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

We have to calculate $$\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin^2((2k-1)^\circ)$$

Because $\sin(180-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$

Now Let $$P=\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin((2k-1)^\circ)$$

Then $$\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin(2k^\circ)\cdot P=\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin((2k-1)^\circ)\cdot \prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin(2k^\circ)$$

So $$\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin(2k^\circ)\cdot P=\frac{1}{2^{44}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin(2k^\circ)$$

So we get $$P=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{89}{2}}}$$

So $$\prod^{45}_{k=1}\sin^2((2k-1)^\circ)=\frac{1}{2^{89}}$$

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer! How'd you get the third-last step from the fourth-last one?

Comment: -1 This answer contains absolutely nothing... In one of the steps you seem to assume we already know $\prod \sin((2k-1)^\circ)$ in order to compute $P = \prod \sin((2k-1)^\circ)$ ? You assume you know the answer to get the answer