# Simplify $\frac{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \cos(2n-1)}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \sin(4n-2)}$, measured in degrees

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Absolutely clueless, any help would be appreciated, especially if it can be understood by a grade $12$ student (me).

The answer is in the form $2^x$, and we are supposed to find value of $x$.

Comment: *not a homework question, this is a question that had come in one of our exams a few weeks back

Comment: Hint: $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you want to evaluate the trig functions in degrees, but it's probably best to explicitly say so.

Comment: I just tried that, we get another series sin1*sin3*sin5*....in the denominator, how do i progress further?

Comment: @Integrand , yes it is in degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By double-angle, we have
$$\require{cancel} 
\frac{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \cos(2n-1)}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \sin(4n-2)} = \frac{\cancel{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \cos(2n-1)}}{2^{45}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{45} \sin(2n-1)\cancel{\cos(2n-1)}} 
=\left(2^{45}\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n-1)\right)^{-1}
$$We can double the product and take the square root
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n-1) = \sqrt{\prod_{n=1}^{90}\sin(2n-1)}
$$This problem was solved by lhf in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766630/what-is-the-value-of-sin-1-circ-sin3-circ-sin5-circ-sin-7-circ-sin-9) using a comment from Hans Lundmark in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1). The links are excellent reading, I would encourage you to look at them. However, to spoil the result, the second product evaluates to $2^{-89}$, whence we have
$$
\left(2^{45}\prod_{n=1}^{45}\sin(2n-1)\right)^{-1} = \left(2^{45}\cdot 2^{-89/2}\right)^{-1}=1/\sqrt{2}
$$