# Closed form for a product of sines

Tags: closed-form, products

From this question [Evaluation of a product of sines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159214/evaluation-of-a-product-of-sines) I allready know that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{k\pi}{n}) = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}.$$

I am interested in a closed form for the following product:
$$\prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{n\pi}{k})$$
where $n$ is a fixed integer.
Does one exist? My math abilities are sadly not sufficient to derive it from the linked question. The reason why I am interested in a closed form is that this product evaluates to 0 at composite numbers, as allready pointed out by @orion in the comments.

For illustration purposes: this is a graph of $f(x) = \prod_{k=2}^{n} \sin(\frac{\pi x}{k})$ with increasing $n$:

[image: Illustration of formula]

Judging by its looks, I doubt that a closed form exists. What we can say is that $f$ is periodic with period $n!$.

Comment: i know nothing about this product,sorry

Comment: Try: Using the fact that $\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-x}}{2i} = \sin(x)$, expand product, rewrite as a sum of $\sin$s

Comment: Also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_functions may limit your ability to simplify the resulting expression beyond a point

Comment: Thanks for the interesting read. I'll try to grasp it

Comment: If anything, it might relate to divisor functions and modular forms. For instance - it will be 0 for any nonprime $n$. Logarithms might help convert it into a sum (ugly sum, but it might be solvable with other standard tools - generating functions, Euler-Maclaurin and similar)