# Finding $ \prod_{n=1}^{999}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{1999}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem. How can we find the product

$$ \prod_{n=1}^{999}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{1999}\right)$$

Comment: No idea how to do this exactly.  If a decimal approximation is an acceptable answer you could use Sage.

Comment: @wildcow: whats source ?

Comment: source : high school problem

Comment: @Young do you attend the NUS high school? This looks like a SMO problem.

Comment: Using complex numbers and eulers formula seem apparent

Answer (score 30):

[$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8395/33989)

Here, let $$x=\prod_{k=1}^{999}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{1999}\right) \tag{1}$$

Since $\sin t=\sin (\pi-t)$, therefore,

$$x=\prod_{k=1}^{999}\sin\left(\frac{(1999-k)\pi}{1999}\right)=\prod_{k=1000}^{1998}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{1999}\right) \tag{2}$$

Multiplying equation $(1)$ by equation $(2)$ gives,

$$x^2=\prod_{k=1}^{1998}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{1999}\right)=\frac{1999}{2^{1998}}$$ $$\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{1999}}{2^{999}}$$

We took $x>0$ because all angles are in $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ quadrant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern. But how can I prove the first indentity: $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Comment: That's pretty neat!

Comment: Can you please explain how u got $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\big(\frac{k\pi}{n}\big)=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: @PhaniRaj: I updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: @Avatar Nice answer!

Comment: @PhaniRaj: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1

Answer (score 6):

I have an even more precise bound: the product is less than

$$(999)! \left(\frac{\pi}{1999}\right)^{999}$$

Use Stirling approximation to get that this in turn is less than

$$ \sqrt{999 e} \left ( \frac{999 \pi}{1999 e}\right )^{999} \approx 4 \times 10^{-237}$$

Answer (score 5):

The first digits of your number are:

```
0.00
```

To get this estimate notice that all terms of the product are less than $1$ and that $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$.

To be more precise your number is between $0$ and $10^{-80}$.

Comment: Hows this helpful?

Comment: @Inceptio: I know more digits of this number than of $\pi$...