# Prove the identity: $\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{n} \right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

suggests use the formula $1+z+\cdots +z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I factorized $1-z^n=(\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1}(\gamma_k-z))(1-z)$ where $\gamma_k$ are the $n$th roots of $1$ $(\gamma_k=\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{n}))$, so if $1\neq z=|z|(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ then
$$1+z+\cdots +z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}=\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1}(\gamma_k-z)$$
then if $|z|=1$ we have $|\gamma_k-z|=2\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}-2\theta\right)$, therefore
$$|1+z+\cdots +z^{n-1}|=\left|\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}\right|=2^{n-1}\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}-2\theta\right).$$
And I dont know what to do next or if what I did is a good way.

Comment: Take the limit $\theta \to 0$, i.e., $z\to 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i prove this identity (by mathematical induction) (rational product of sines)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324609/how-can-i-prove-this-identity-by-mathematical-induction-rational-product-of-s)