# What is wrong with my method for probability that n points on a circle are in one semicircle

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

So I understand the method used in this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/661579/162041), and I know my method is incorrect, but I was just looking for an explanation why.

I was thinking that if I choose any spot on the circumference, there's a $1/2^{n}$ probability that all $n$ points lie in the semicircle starting from that spot on the circumference. Why couldn't you just integrate this probability from 0 to 1 representing moving the spot around the whole circle?

Again, I know this is the wrong and just looking for reasoning why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an obvious way to integrate something to get the right answer.  Integrating is basically a form of addition (or (weighted) averaging if you prefer), but the things you're adding are *not disjoint events*.

E.g. let $E_\theta$ be the event that all the $n$ points are in the semicircle starting at the angle $\theta$ and going clockwise.  Then for all $\theta, P(E_\theta) = 1/2^n$.  But how do you add $E_\theta$ and $E_{\theta + \epsilon}$ for some small $\epsilon$?  Those are overlapping semicircles.  I find it hard to imagine any integral like $\int_0^{2\pi} P(E_\theta) \,\,\text{blah} \,\, d \theta$ would give you the right answer.

In particular, your original suggestion is equivalent to saying $\text{blah} = {1\over 2\pi}$, which is the density for picking the semicircle uniformly, so the result is $\int_0^{2\pi} P(E_\theta) {1\over 2\pi} d \theta = 1/2^n = $ Prob that a random semicircle (the one at a random $\theta$) contains all $n$ points (as Brian also pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning would be correct if you wanted the probability that all $n$ points are in a *random* semicircle.  The desired probability, however, is the probability that all $n$ points all fall within the same (but not predetermined) semicircle.

Thus, for example, a single point obviously falls within the same semicircle as itself.  However, integration gives the probability that the point falls within a randomly selected semicircle, which is $1/2$.

Comment: So I understand the probability all $n$ points are in a random semicircle is $1/2^{n}$, and I know integrating from 0 to 1 doesn't change this. But is there a formulation or way to integrate this probability moving the beginning of the semicircle all the way around the circle?