# Why are we not multiplying 1/n conditional probability of selecting disjoint points in the question - "prob. of N points within a semi-circle"

Tags: probability, geometry, conditional-probability, puzzle, geometric-probability

This is my first question on stackexchange - so apologies in advance if I haven't been able to follow the best practices while asking this question.

I am trying to understand the solution to question "Probability of n points lying within a semi-circle". The question has been asked and answered here - [Probability that n points on a circle are in one semicircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325141/927405).

I am struggling with a statement in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/325168/927405. I understand that the n points are disjoint in a way that only one of the n points can have all the points within a semi-cicrle in particular angular direction. My question is - why are we not multiplying (1/n) for the (conditional) probability of selecting the right point?

I am drawing a parallel that while calculating probability of different outcomes in 2 coin tosses - we say that if I get heads on first toss, prob. of getting tails in 2nd toss is 1/2. Likewise we can get a TH. HT and TH are both disjoint but while calculating final answer - we don't say that if I choose heads first, then the prob of tails in second toss is 1/2 and we can also have a TH and since both are disjoint - let's add them up 1/2 + 1/2 and prob. of different outcomes would be 1 (which we know is incorrect answer because we need to multiply the probability of getting first heads / tails too!)

Similarly, why are we not multiplying 1/n for the probability of selecting the right starting point in this "N point in a semicircle question"? (which will lead to the answer $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$)

Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 : Very nicely presented question: good work shown, good reference to pre-existing mathSE posts, nice explicit questions concerning these posts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First see that the events are mutually exclusive (at least when n >2).  So the probability any one of them occurs is the the sum of the probabilities each of them occurs, not the average.  And the probability say that point $2$ is the leading point of a semicircle is $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ not $\frac1{n2^{n-1}}$, and due to symmetry/exchangeability the same is true for each of the other points, making the final answer  $\frac n{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: @Henry - thank you for the interest. I understand the events are mutually exclusive. Also, I agree that once we have picked a leading point then probability that remaining points lie within a semi-circle is $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$. But once a leading point has all remaining points in a semi-circle - no other point can satisfy this condition i.e. prob of remaining points being in a semi-circle from any other leading point is zero (that is why they are mutually excl). So why are we summing the probabilities of other points? I have tried to draw this parallel in a more familiar coin problem in my ques.

Comment: (cont'd) ... maybe another way to put it is - the probability that any point  is the the correct / desired leading point is 1/n. Therefore, my logic is
$$$$
P(n points in a semi circle) = P(point 2 to n are in a semi-circle | point 1 is correct leading point) - add this up for all other points
$$$$
So while we are adding these mutually exclusive events (that only one of them can be a correct starting point) but we also need to multiply the probability that point  is the correct leading point

Comment: If you throw a 6-sided die, the probability of it being even is the probability of it being 2 plus the probability of it being 4 plus the probability of it being 6, i.e. the sum of probabilities of mutually exclusive events.  With the circle points, you have the probability  point 1 leads a semicircle plus the probability  point 2 leads a semicircle plus ... .  The probability  $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ that point 1 leads a semicircle of all the other points  already takes into account the probability it is the correct point

Comment: @Henry thanks again! This analogy is helpful and convincing.

Answer (score 1):

*Compilation of comments:*

First see that the events are mutually exclusive (at least when $n >2$). So the probability any one of them occurs is the the sum of the probabilities each of them occurs, not the average.

The probability say that point $2$ is the leading point of a semicircle is $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ not $\frac1{n2^{n-1}}$, and due to symmetry/exchangeability the same is true for each of the other points, making the final answer $\frac n{2^{n-1}}$.

If you throw a $6$-sided die, the probability of it being even is the probability of it being $2$ plus the probability of it being $4$ plus the probability of it being $6$, i.e. the sum of probabilities of mutually exclusive events.

With the circle points, you have the probability point $1$ leads a semicircle plus the probability point $2$ leads a semicircle plus ... . The probability $\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ that point $2$ leads a semicircle of all the other points already takes into account the probability it is the correct point.