# Tridiagonal matrix w/trigonometric eigenvalues

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

Let $n$ be a natural number and $B$ be the $n\times n$ square matrix of $0$'s and $1$'s
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
 0     & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
 1     & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
 0     & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 \vdots    & \vdots & \ddots & 0 & 1 \\
 0     & 0  & \ldots & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
 Is there a way to find the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix D, such that the eigenvalues of the product matrix $DB$ are
$$
 2\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right), \,\, k=1,2,\dots,n.
$$
 The pertaining old question: [Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal trigonometric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400664/eigenvalues-of-a-tridiagonal-trigonometric-matrix)

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237740/2451

Comment: pertains Chebyshev polynomials of the first and second kind...

Comment: The proof of the existence of the diagonal matrix $D$ w/alternating in sign entries involves special matrices and continued fractions...

Comment: Would you accept an answer where the angle is $\frac{2k\pi}{2N+1}$ or $\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2N+1}$ for any$N$? Currently, I am getting cosine function but I might be able to fix that.

Comment: @Vini Yes, seems like a good progress...

Comment: @Vini Editted the question...