# Solve $x\sqrt{10} = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{90} \sin(k), x\in \mathbb Q$.

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Can someone help me with this question? I've found a solution but it's not a very nice one. I used 6 times the relation $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$. There's got to be a better way.

$x\sqrt{10} = \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{90} \sin(k)$, k in degrees.

Comment: $x=\dfrac{\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{90} \sin(k)}{\sqrt {10}}?$

Comment: Numerical value

Comment: Presumably $k$ is in degrees, and the product is a rational multiple of $\sqrt{10}$, which Pedro was assigned to find.

Comment: Apply [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1), which is somewhat complicated.

Let $S$ be the product $\prod_{k=1}^{90} \sin k^\circ $. Then $S^2 = \prod_{k=1}^{179} \sin k^\circ  = \frac{ 180} { 2^{179}}$

Hence $S = \sqrt{ 10} \frac{3}{2^{89} }$.

---

I believe your method of using $\sin 2\theta$ repeatedly is better, in part because the proof of the quoted theorem is complicated.