# Value of $\sin (2^\circ)\cdot \sin (4^\circ)\cdot \sin (6^\circ)\cdots \sin (90^\circ) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I calculate the value of

1. $\sin (1^\circ)\cdot \sin (3^\circ)\cdot \sin (5^\circ)\cdots \sin (89^\circ)$
2. $\sin (2^\circ)\cdot \sin (4^\circ)\cdot \sin (6^\circ)\cdots \sin (90^\circ)$

**My solution:** Let $$A =  \sin (1^\circ)\cdot \sin (3^\circ)\cdot \sin (5^\circ)\cdots \sin (89^\circ)$$

$$B =  \sin (2^\circ)\cdot \sin (4^\circ)\cdot \sin (6^\circ)\cdots \sin (90^\circ)$$

Now $$
\begin{eqnarray}
A\cdot B &=& (\sin 1^\circ \cdot \sin 89^\circ)\cdot (\sin2^\circ\cdot \sin 88^\circ)\cdots(\sin 44^\circ\cdot \sin 46^\circ) \cdot \sin 45^\circ \\
&=& (\sin 1^\circ\cdot \cos1^\circ)\cdot (\sin2^\circ\cdot \cos 2^\circ)\cdots(\sin 44^\circ\cdot \cos 44^\circ)\cdot \sin 45^\circ \\
&=& \frac{1}{2^{44}}\left[\sin(2^\circ)\cdot \sin (4^\circ)\cdots \sin(88^\circ) \cdot \sin (90^\circ)\right]\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2^{\frac{89}{2}}}\cdot B
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Which implies that $$B\cdot \left(A-2^{-\frac{89}{2}}\right) = 0$$

So $A = 2^{-\frac{89}{2}}$ because $B\neq 0$.

But I do not understand how can I calculate the value of $B$. Can we calculate these values using complex numbers?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe it has a nice form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the identity
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}} \tag{1}$$
Putting $n=180$, it gives 
$$ \left(\sin (1^\circ)\sin (2^\circ)\dots \sin (89^\circ)\right)^2= \frac{180}{2^{179}} \tag{2}$$
The value of 
$$\boxed{ \sin(2^{\circ})\sin(4^{\circ}) \dots \sin(90^{\circ}) = \sqrt{\frac{180}{2^{179}}}\div \sqrt{\frac 1 {2^{89}}} = \sqrt{\frac{180}{2^{90}}}} \tag{3}$$

The [required value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BProduct%5BSin%5B2%20n%20Pi/180%5D,%20%7Bn,%201,%2045%7D%5D%5D) seems to be in agreement with [calculated value.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5B180/2%5E90%5D)
The proof of identity $(1)$ can be found at the end of [this pdf](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch1.pdf).

Comment: The formula is also found in several questions on MSE, for instance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1