# How prove this identity $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{k\pi}{tn}}=\frac{\sqrt[t]{n}}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: trigonometry

> show that：
>
> $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin{\dfrac{k\pi}{tn}}=\dfrac{\sqrt[t]{n}}{2^{n-1}}?(not, true),t\in N^{+}$$

maybe for $t$is real numbers also true?

I can show when $t=1$ case.
because I use
$$z^{n-1}-1=(z-x_{1})(z-x^2_{1})\cdots (z-x^{n-1}_{1}),x_{1}=\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{n}}+i\sin{\dfrac{2\pi}{n}}$$
also see [Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k \pi}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1?lq=1)

But for $t\neq 1$,I can't use this identity

Comment: Is $t$ an integer?

Comment: But maybe for $t\in R$ is also true?

Comment: I do not think the statement is true for $ t = 3, n = 2$. It states that $ \sin \frac{ \pi} { 3 \times 2} = \frac{ \sqrt[3]{2} } { 2} $. It is clear the RHS is not equal to $ \frac{1}{2} $. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @CalvinLin you're right, and I too was skeptical of the formula.

Comment: @CalvinLin,if my is not true,then How find it?

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for which the formula cannot be true is that $\log(\sin x)$ is an integrable function over $(0,1)$, hence for $t\in\mathbb{N}$ it is expected that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\sin\frac{\pi k}{t n}\approx n\int_{0}^{\pi/t}\log\sin x\,dx \approx -n\frac{1+\log\frac{t}{\pi}}{t}$$
by Riemann sums, while:
$$\log\frac{\sqrt[t]{n}}{2^{n-1}}\approx -n\log 2+\frac{\log n}{t}$$
has the wrong magnitude.

To compute the product, a possibility is given by the Fourier series identity:
$$-\log\sin x = -\log 2-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}. $$

Comment: Nice,But we can find this closed form?