# $\lim_n \sum_k^{n-1} \tfrac1{1-\rho^k-\rho^{n-k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

If $|\rho|<1$, show that, when $n\to\infty$:

$$
\frac1{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{1-\rho^k-\rho^{n-k}} =
1 + \frac1n \frac{2\big(\psi_{\rho}(1)+\log\big(1-\rho)\big)}{\log \rho} + o\big(\tfrac1n\big)
$$

where $\psi_a$ is the [a-polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). In particular 
$\psi_{\rho}(1) = \frac{\partial \log \Gamma_{\rho}(x)}{\partial x}\Big|_{x=1}$ where $\Gamma_a$ is the [a-Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-GammaFunction.html).

---

FWIW, the question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222259/how-to-prove-that-sum-k-1n-1-frac11-e2-pi-i-k-n-fracn-12/1222274#1222280).

Comment: Have you tried expanding the summand into its [binomial $($or trinomial$)$ series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then making use of certain series for q-polygamma functions and the [natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) ?