# Finding $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k\pi}n$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Finding $$\mu=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k\pi}n$$
I thought $$z^n=1=e^{i2\pi}\implies z=\cos\frac{2k\pi}n+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}n\quad k\in\{1,2,...,n-1\}$$
Now we have:
$$\begin{align}\mu&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{z+\bar z}{2}\\&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{e^{i\theta}+ e^{-i\theta}}{2}\\&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{-i\theta}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+ e^{2i\theta})\\
\\&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}n(1+2+...(n-1))}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+ e^{2i\theta})\\
\\&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}e^{-i(n-1)\pi}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+ e^{2i\theta})\\
\\&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+ e^{2i\theta})\end{align}$$
Now since $(e^{2i\theta})^{n/2}=1$:
$$\Theta(z)=z^{n/2}-1=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(z-e^{2i\theta})$$
At $(-1)$:
$$\Theta(-1)=(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+e^{2i\theta})=(-1)^{n/2}-1=e^{in\pi/2}-1=i\sin n\pi/2$$
It turns out something imaginary (but it's not clearly) also I would like to work on:
$$\nu=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{2k\pi}n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{e^{i\theta}- e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$$
Similarly:
$$\nu=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}(-1)^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^n(e^{2i\theta}-1)=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}(-1)^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\Theta(1)=\frac1{2^{n-1}i\sin (n-1)\pi/2}0=0$$
But this is also not zero?
The earlier $\eta$ is obviously:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan\frac{2k\pi}n=\eta=\frac{\mu}{\nu}$$

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1) is a related question.

Comment: @mathlove can you help with my mistake?

Comment: @ADG Can you please explain why $z^{n/2}-1=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(z-e^{2i\theta})$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin as $(e^{i\theta})^n=1$ so $(e^{2i\theta})^{n/2}=1$ therefore $e^{2i\theta}$ are the roots of $z^{n/2}=1$

Comment: @ADG It turns out not. There is degree $n/2$ "polynomial" on the left and degree $n-1$ polynomial (respect to $z$) on the right.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin oh that's the mistake, then can you help improve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}n\right)
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+e^{4\pi ik/n}\right)e^{-2\pi ik/n}\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\left[\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(-z^2+e^{4\pi ik/n}\right)\right]_{\large z=i}\\
&=\left[\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(z^2-e^{4\pi ik/n}\right)\right]_{\large z=i}\\
&=\left[\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(z-e^{2\pi ik/n}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(z+e^{2\pi ik/n}\right)\right]_{\large z=i}\\[3pt]
&=\left[\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}\frac{z^n-(-1)^n}{z+1}\right]_{\large z=i}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(i^n-1)(i^n-(-1)^n)}{-2}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{2(-1)^n-i^n(1+(-1)^n)}{-2}\\[12pt]
&=\cos(n\pi/2)-(-1)^n
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}n\right)
&=\frac{\cos(n\pi/2)-(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\cos(n\pi/2)-\cos(n\pi)}{2^{n-1}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\sin(n\pi/4)\sin(3n\pi/4)}{2^{n-2}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I always get notifications starting with "$$\begin{align}... "and I intutively know it's you robjohn, thanks!.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Identities_without_variables, and cos(npi/2)=0 too!

Comment: Am I missing it? I don't see this identity there.

Comment: no you're not, that's me just relating it. and ok only odd multiples go to zero sorry

Comment: I found this: $(-1)^{-n}2^{1-n}\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)-1\right)$

Comment: @JanEerland: that differs by the sign of $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)$ from my answer. Have you checked that numerically?

Comment: @robjohn yes I did, and I get that!

Comment: @JanEerland: Oh, the sign only differs when $n$ is odd, and then $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}2\right)=0$. So our answers actually *do* agree.