# Evaluate $ \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) ... \cos(999x) $ where $x = \frac{2 \pi}{ 1999 }$.

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

Evaluate

$$ \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) ... \cos(999x) $$

where $x = \frac{2 \pi}{ 1999 }$.

---

**Attempt:**

Let $A = \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) ... \cos(999x)$, $B = \sin(x) \sin(2x) \sin(3x) ... \sin(999x)$. Then

$$ AB = \frac{\sin(2x) \sin(4x) ... \sin(1998x)}{2^{999}} $$

then

$$ A = \frac{\sin(2x) \sin(4x) ... \sin(1998x)}{2^{999}(\sin(x) \sin(2x) ... \sin(999x))}   $$
$$ = \frac{\sin(1000x) \sin(1002x) ... \sin(1998x)}{2^{999}(\sin(x) \sin(3x)... \sin(997x) \sin(999x))} $$

What to do after this? If I can find $1999x = 2\pi$ then it would be nice.

Comment: $sin (2\pi-x) = - sin (x) $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284744/find-the-value-of-cos-x-cos-2x-cos-999x-given-that-x-frac-2-pi1999

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-left-fracr-pi15-right