# Evaluate $ \cos a \cos 2 a \cos 3 a \cdots \cos 999 a $ where $a=\frac{2 \pi}{1999}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate
> $
> \cos a \cos 2 a \cos 3 a \cdots \cos 999 a
> $
> where $a=\frac{2 \pi}{1999}$

I know this question has already been answered many times but my doubt is different

Solution: Let $P$ denote the desired product, and let

$
Q=\sin a \sin 2 a \sin 3 a \cdots \sin 999 a
$

Then
$
\begin{aligned}
2^{999} P Q=&(2 \sin a \cos a)(2 \sin 2 a \cos 2 a) \cdots(2 \sin 999 a \cos 999 a) \\
=& \sin 2 a \sin 4 a \cdots \sin 1998 a \\
=&(\sin 2 a \sin 4 a \cdots \sin 998 a)[-\sin (2 \pi-1000 a)] \\
& \cdot[-\sin (2 \pi-1002 a)] \cdots[-\sin (2 \pi-1998 a)] \\
=& (\sin 2 a \sin 4 a \cdots \sin 998 a) \sin 999 a \sin 997 a \cdots \sin a=Q
\end{aligned}
$

**how they got this last step from previous one** ???

Comment: Where did you see this (alleged) proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284744/find-the-value-of-cos-x-cos-2x-cos-999x-given-that-x-frac-2-pi1999

Comment: The definition of $a$ is used in that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reach penultimate step, use $\sin(2\pi-\theta)=-\sin\theta$, and to go from penultimate to ultimate step, use
$$2\pi-1000a=2\pi-1000\cdot\frac{2\pi}{1999}=2\pi\left(1-\frac{1000}{1999}\right)=2\pi\frac{999}{1999}=999a$$
Also, there comes out $(-1)^{999-500+1}$ if one counts only even numbers from $1000$ to $1998$.