# Show that $\cot \frac{\pi}{2m}\cot \frac{2\pi}{2m}\cot \frac{3\pi}{2m}...\cot \frac{(m-1)\pi}{2m}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Prove:

> $$\cot \frac{\pi}{2m}\cot \frac{2\pi}{2m}\cot \frac{3\pi}{2m}...\cot \frac{(m-1)\pi}{2m}=1$$

This is a roots of unity problem. I managed to show a similar example for $\cos$ by the following:

$z^m-1=0$ with roots $1,e^{2\pi /m},...,e^{2(m-1)\pi /m}$ Put the roots into a polynomial with linear factors:

$(z-1)(z-e^{2\pi /m})...(e^{2(m-1)\pi /m})=z^m-1$ and divide by $z-1$ to get:

$$(z-e^{2\pi /m})...(e^{2(m-1)\pi /m})=1+z+...+z^{m-1}$$

Evaluation at $z=1$ with some complex conjugation (I multiply 2 conjugated equations) yields the result.

I'll be happy to expand on my current work if required.

Edit: Thought I'd add a similar [$\sin$ summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1?rq=1)

Comment: Are $n$ and $m$ related?

Comment: yes, sorry, typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the fact that
$$\left(\cot x\right)\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\right)=1.$$ The product of the entry that is $k$ from the beginning and the entry that is $k$ from the end is $1$.  (If $m$ is even, there is a "middle" term, but it is $1$.)

Comment: I see, so I simply need to pair up the root according to the formula above?

Comment: P.S. I changed it to $m$, I typed it up too late yesterday. There are $m-1$ of them, but for the formula to hold I'd have to have even number of $\cot$ functions. This would mean that only odd $m$ will work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you give me some insight into how you came up with the formula?

Comment: @GRS: Odd number of terms (that is, $m$ even), works too, in that case the middle term is $\cot(\pi/4)$, which  is $1$.

Comment: @GRS:  You are welcome. You also know the formula, in the equivalent form $\tan(90^\circ-x)=\frac{1}{\tan x}$.   Switch to the complementary angle and the $\tan$ flips.

Comment: You can also get it from $\sin(\pi/2-x)=\cos x$, $\cos(\pi/2-x)=\sin x$.

Comment: Thanks, this is much simpler to derive using $\cos$ and $\sin$

Comment: @GRS: You are welcome.  Note that the basic idea is similar to the one for adding up $1+2+3+\cdots+50$. The sum of the first and last is $51$, as is the sum of second and next to last, and so on.In our case it is multiplication, not addition, but there is a similar "symmetry" thing going on.

Comment: I tried to derive your results, and it was much easier than expected, almost in a single line :)

Comment: Yes, this one is very quick. It uses much less machinery that the $\cos$ one referred to in your question.