# Closed form for $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{\pi k}{n})^{n-k}$

Tags: trigonometry, products

**Question:** I am hoping to analytically continue the function:

$F(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{\pi k}{n})^{n-k}$

to $n=1/2$. My understanding is that means I will need a closed form for this product. What is a closed form of the above product? (Or are there other methods for performing the analytic continuation without having a closed form?)

**Attempt:** A similar product satisfies the identity

$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\frac{\pi k}{n}) = n 2^{1-n}$.

A proof of the above identity is given in another post ([Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k \pi}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1)). I have gone through the proofs given there and tried to extend the techniques used to my case, but no luck so far.

Any help is appreciated - a full solution, or just suggestions of theorems or related identities which may be of use.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but you might try the identity $\sin x = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$. Also, reindexing the product by $j = n-k$ and using $\sin(\pi - x) = \sin x$ will give the product a slightly simpler form.

Comment: Correction. $\sin x = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We break up the product in a different way (analogous to changing the order of products):
$$\begin{align}
F(n) &= \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{3\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \quad \vdots \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)}.
\end{align}$$
(Note there are $n-1$ of the first term, $n-2$ of the second, down to one of the last). Now, consider $F(n)^2$: it is sufficient to do this and square root afterwards since every term in the finite product is positive, so the whole thing must be positive. Again, we reorder the terms:
$$\begin{align}
F(n)^2 &= \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \\ 
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \times \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \quad \vdots \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)}.
\end{align}$$
(so basically I've taken the triangle of terms, flipped it over and made a rectangle).
Now, $\sin{\left(\frac{(n-k)\pi}{n}\right)} = \sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}$, so we can change the terms in the upper-right triangle as follows:
$$\begin{align}
F(n)^2 &= \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)} \\ 
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \times \sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \quad \vdots \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \times \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)} \\
&\quad \times \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \dotsm \sin{\left(\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\right)} \sin{\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)}.
\end{align}$$
But of course this is just $n-1+1=n$ copies of $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin{\left( \frac{k\pi}{n} \right)} = n/2^{n-1}$, so we find
$$ F(n) = \sqrt{\frac{n^n}{2^{n(n-1)}}} = \frac{n^{n/2}}{2^{n(n-1)/2}}, $$
as conjectured by Claude Leibovici.

Comment: I admire this kind of proofs ! Thanks for providing this answer.

Comment: Very neat! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer since based on observation.*

Looking at the values of $$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)^{n-k}$$ for small odd values of $n$ reveals some interesting patterns as shown in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 3 & \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{8} = \frac{{3^{3/2}}}{2^3}\\
 5 & \frac{25 \sqrt{5}}{1024}= \frac{{5^{5/2}}}{2^{2\times 5}} \\
 7 & \frac{343 \sqrt{7}}{2097152}= \frac{{7^{7/2}}}{2^{3\times 7}}
\end{array}
\right)$$ This made me thinking about $$\large{P_n=\frac{n^{n/2}}{2^{n(n-1)/2}}}$$ which seems to be verified for all $n$.

I must confess that I should be more than happy to see a proof coming here.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I checked this in Mathematica up to n=1000 and it agrees. Did you check any further?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{n - k}\pars{\pi k \over n} =
\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{n - \pars{n - k}}\pars{\pi \bracks{n - k} \over n} =
\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{k}\pars{\pi k \over n}
\\[5mm] & =
\root{\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{n - k}\pars{\pi k \over n}}
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{k}\pars{\pi k \over n}}} =
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin\pars{\pi k \over n}}^{n/2}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> As given by the OP and in the [cited link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1),
>   $\ds{\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin\pars{\pi k \over n} = {n \over 2^{n - 1}}}$. So, expression \eqref{1} becomes:

$$
\prod_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\sin^{n - k}\pars{\pi k \over n} =
\pars{n \over 2^{n - 1}}^{n/2} = \bbx{\ds{n^{n/2} \over 2^{n\pars{n -1}/2}}}
$$