# Evaluating a product of sines

Tags: trigonometry, products

I saw this product from a question, but got deleted.
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}$$
Naturally, I was curious, and evaluated this in mathematica, which suprisingly turns out to be:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=n\tag{1}$$
From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1), we have:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=\frac n{2^{n-1}}$$
My question is how is $(1)$ evaluated?

Comment: They are the same. $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2a_k)=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$

Answer (score 2):

You should think about what the product sign actually means:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=2\sin\frac{1\pi}{n}\cdot 2\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}\cdot \cdots \cdot 2\sin\frac{(n-2)\pi}{n}\cdot2\sin\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}$$

so if we wish to take out the two to the front, we'd get

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=(2\cdot2\cdot\cdots\cdot2)\sin\frac{1\pi}{n}\cdot \sin\frac{2\pi}{n}\cdot \cdots \cdot\sin\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}$$

Comment: Yes. It is clear now, thus taken off the question. How about the evaluation of $(1)$?

Comment: Simply use the [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1) question, and rewrite using what I wrote in my answer