# Using mathematical induction to prove products of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, products

So I have this identity or result from studying polygons and complex numbers which states:

$$\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{\bigg(\cos\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{n}-\cos\frac{\theta}{n}\bigg)^2  +\bigg(\sin\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{n}-\sin\frac{\theta}{n}\bigg)^2}=n $$

I know how to prove this directly using trigonometric identities, and roots of unity of complex numbers, which is quite a lengthy process in my opinion. But my question is, how do I prove this using induction?

For instance going to the induction step straight way give us:

**Step I:** 
Let $n = k,$ if $P(k)$ holds true then for $P(k+1)$ we have:
$$P(k)=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\sqrt{\bigg(\cos\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k}-\cos\frac{\theta}{k}\bigg)^2  +\bigg(\sin\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k}-\sin\frac{\theta}{k}\bigg)^2}=k $$
$$P(k+1)=\prod_{j=0}^{k}\sqrt{\bigg(\cos\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k+1}-\cos\frac{\theta}{k+1}\bigg)^2  +\bigg(\sin\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k+1}-\sin\frac{\theta}{k+1}\bigg)^2}   $$

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Furthermore I do not know what to do next after the induction step like how it is carried out in normal induction. I would appreciate some guidance or a possible root to carry out the induction on this result.

Comment: Is $P(k)$ a proposition or a number? Anyway induction does not strike me as a suitable method here.

Comment: Why would knowing $\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k}$, $j=0,1,\dots,k-1$ tell you anything about $\frac{\theta+2j\pi}{k+1}$, $j=0,1,\dots,k$?

Comment: Wait let me edit my post

Comment: So is the above product not possible to show using induction, in such a way that the LHS gives us $k+1$ with some algebra like standard high school induction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1

Comment: Thanks for that but I know how to prove using the direct method, I just want to know if we can prove this using induction thats all.

Comment: Anyway, induction, or any other method, obviously won't work, because the $j=0$ contributes a 0, making the whole product $0$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Hmmm I see, so I guess Induction is not the way to go, I will try to use the direct approach then. Thanks !