# How to calculate this product: $\sin 1^\circ\times\sin 2^\circ\times\cdots\times\sin90^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

How to calculate this product:
$$\sin 1^\circ\times\sin 2^\circ\times\cdots\times\sin90^\circ$$

Comment: Hint: $\sin(90^\circ)=1$, so you can drop that term. For the rest, pair them up as $\sin(x)\sin(90^\circ-x)=\frac12\sin(2x)$. You will also have an extra term $\sin(45^\circ)=2^{-0.5}$. You'll have to repeat this pairing process a few times.

Comment: First, make sure your calculator is in degree mode.

Comment: The square of your product is the case $n=180$ of [Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k \pi}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1).

Comment: I get $1.53268\times 10^{-26}$