# Evaluate a product of sines of angles of multiples of 4 with some terms missing

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

The value of
$$\sin 4^o  \sin 8^o \sin 16^o \sin 20^o \sin 28^o \sin 32^o\cdots \sin 76^o \sin 80^o \sin 88^o$$ equals $N$. Find the value of $[2^{15}N]$.

This seems like I can use complex numbers real parts but not sure how. Multiplying by $\cos 4^o$ only complicates stuff. Please help.

Comment: Have you forgot $\cos 84^\circ\;$?

Comment: No all the multiples of 12 are missing

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Consider the identity (see e.g. [Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{k \pi}{n} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1) )
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$
and note that, since $\sin(x^{\circ})=\sin(180^{\circ} -x^{\circ})$, it follows that the square of your product is equal to
$$N^2=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{44}\sin \left( \frac{4\pi}{180}\right)}{\prod_{k=1}^{14}\sin \left( \frac{12\pi}{180}\right)}.$$
Can you take it from here? What is the value of $2^{15}N$?

Comment: Thanks super helpful.