# How to prove that $\sum_{ k= 1}^{N-1} \sin(\frac{k}{N} \pi)^{-2} = (N^2 - 1)/3$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

I find the equality
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k = 1}^{N-1} \sin(\frac{k}{N}\pi)^{-2} = \frac{N^2 - 1}{3},
\end{equation}
during study.

Just wonder how can I prove it?

Short matlab code to do the verification:

```
N = 10;
xv = (1:N-1)/N*pi; 
error = sum(sin(xv).^(-2)) - (N^2 -1)/3
```

EDIT2: I found the proof of $\Pi_{k = 1}^{N-1} \sin(\frac{k \pi}{N}) = \frac{N}{2^{N-1}}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1) it may be helpful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Gary, yes, thank you very much for your reply! I will close it.