# Prove the identity: $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right) = N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, infinite-product

Context: trying to diagonalize a sparse matrix here
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 \eta^2 & -\eta & & & -\eta \\ 
  -\eta & 2 & -1 & & \\
  & & \ddots & & \\
  & & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
  -\eta & & & -1 & 2 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

By using the constant term of the characteristic polynomial, I got the identity below.

$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right) = N$$

If anyone has a nice proof for it, do share!

E.g. of numerical verification
[WolframAlpha: $N=101$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Product%5B4*Power%5Bsin%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bk*%CF%80%2C2*101%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N}=\frac{1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{N}}2,~~~\cos^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N}=\frac{1+\cos\frac{k\pi}{N}}2$$
we have:

$$\cos\frac{k\pi}N=-\cos\frac{(N-k)\pi}N$$

hence,
$$1-\cos\frac{k\pi}N=1+\cos\frac{(N-k)\pi}N$$
From symmetry, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{N} \right) =\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 1+\cos\frac{(N-k)\pi}N\right)= \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 1+\cos\frac{k\pi}{N} \right)$$

Therefore,  we get

$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right) = \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \cos^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right)=P$$

Next, multiply them, and use $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$

$$P^2=\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right)  \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \cos^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right)=\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{N} \right)=\left[\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 2 \sin \frac{k\pi}{N} \right)\right]^2$$

We know: [$\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{N-1}\left(2\sin\frac{k \pi}{N} \right)= N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/prove-that-prod-k-1n-1-sin-frack-pin-fracn2n-1), hence

$$P^2=N^2$$

Finally,

$$\boxed{\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right) = \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left( 4 \cos^2 \frac{k\pi}{2N} \right)=N}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the product is a real positive number $P$. Using euler's theorem, the product equals
$$P=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(-(e^{ik\pi/2n}-e^{-ik\pi/2n})^2)$$
$$=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}-e^{-ik\pi/n}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2$$
$$=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}-e^{-ik\pi/n}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2$$
$$=(-1)^{n-1}e^{i\pi(n+1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2$$
$$=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2$$
Now we compute $P\overline{P}$
$$P\overline{P}=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(e^{-ik\pi/n}-1)^2\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2n-1}(e^{ik\pi/n}-1)^2\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2n-1}(1-e^{ik\pi/n})^2\right)$$
If $f(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $e^{ik\pi/n}$ for all $k\in [2n-1]$, we know $f(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^{2n-1}$, hence the product is equal to
$$=\frac{1}{4}f(1)^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}(2n)^2$$
$$=n^2$$
Since $P$ is real and positive, we must have $P=n$.